# MarshalException: Failed to communicate due to unread block data

Tags: java, exception, serialization, marshalling, rmi

I am getting this exception in my java program.Can anyone have idea on it?
`MarshalException: Failed to communicate due to unread block data`

```
java.rmi.MarshalException: Failed to communicate.
    Problem during marshalling/unmarshalling; nested exception is: 
                java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
com.naresh.product.common.exception.ApplicationException: 
    java.rmi.MarshalException: Failed to communicate.
    Problem during marshalling/unmarshalling; nested exception is: 
                java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data

    at com.naresh.product.client.library.util.ServerDelegate.search(Unknown Source)
    at com.naresh.product.client.Product.workflow.form4.ProductForm4DashboardView.refreshDashboard(Unknown Source)
    at com.naresh.product.client.Product.workflow.form4.ProductForm4DashboardView.access$3(Unknown Source)
    at com.naresh.product.client.Product.workflow.form4.ProductForm4DashboardView$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
    at com.naresh.product.client.Product.workflow.form4.ProductForm4DashboardView.refreshDashboard(Unknown Source)
    at com.naresh.product.client.Product.workflow.form4.ProductForm4DashboardView$5.widgetSelected(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.naresh.product.client.app.Application.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)

Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: Failed to communicate.  Problem during marshalling/unmarshalling; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data

    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.handleException(SocketClientInvoker.java:122)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:646)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:122)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1634)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:548)
    at org.jboss.invocation.unified.interfaces.UnifiedInvokerProxy.invoke(UnifiedInvokerProxy.java:183)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeInvoker(InvokerInterceptor.java:365)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invoke(InvokerInterceptor.java:197)
    at org.jboss.proxy.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.StatelessSessionInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInterceptor.java:112)
    at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:100)
    at $Proxy1.search(Unknown Source)

    ... 34 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data

    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2376)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1360)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObjectVersion2_2(JavaSerializationManager.java:239)
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObject(JavaSerializationManager.java:133)
    at org.jboss.remoting.marshal.serializable.SerializableUnMarshaller.read(SerializableUnMarshaller.java:120)
    at org.jboss.invocation.unified.marshall.InvocationUnMarshaller.read(InvocationUnMarshaller.java:59)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.versionedRead(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:957)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:586)

    ... 45 more
```

Why this exception is comming. Do you guys have any idea to solve it?

Comment: Whatever you're receiving has a custom `readObject()` method with bugs in it.

Answer (score 2):

From  `java.io.ObjectInputStream.BlockDataInputStream` Javadoc :

**boolean java.io.ObjectInputStream.BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(boolean newmode) throws IOException**

> Sets block data mode to the given mode (true == on, false == off) and
>   returns the previous mode value. If the new mode is the same as the
>   old mode, no action is taken. Throws IllegalStateException if block
>   data mode is being switched from on to off while unconsumed block data
>   is still present in the stream.

But in your stacktrace, the problem takes its origin from `org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker` which processes deserialization on some objects.

So, you can imagine that it is hard to guess the cause of this error with just a stacktrace.
With a little luck, you could have a precise answer.
But if it is not the case, I propose you some tracks :

- to update or downgrade the version of the jboss lib if possible. Maybe, it is a bug.
- to run your server with breakpoints to discover the root of the problem.
- to ask your question to JBoss support

Comment: I tried but sorry to inform this not solve my problem.And i don't think jboss support team can't able to give any solution.

Comment: With breakpoint at runtime you should be able to enter in the code which triggers the exception.  If jboss support, owner of the lib can't help you, don't be hurry for having a precise answer here.